# Propositional Resolution

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm trying to solve a problem in Propositional Logic (Resolution).

Given the formula F in CNF:

```
F = {{¬p, ¬q, r}, {¬p, ¬q, s}, {¬p1, ¬q1, r1}, {¬r1, ¬s, s1}, {p}, {q}, {q1}, {p1}, {¬s1}}.
```

The result should be:

```
{¬p, ¬q, s}, {¬r1, ¬s, s1}, {¬p, ¬q, ¬r1, s1}, {p}, {¬q, ¬r1, s1}, {q}, {¬r1, s1}, {¬s}
, {¬r1}, {¬p1, ¬q1, r1}, {¬p1, ¬q1}, {q1}, {¬p1}, {p1},□.
```

As we have □ in the last clause ,an empty clause it's unsatisfiable.

**My result**

```
{r},{¬p,¬q}
```

**How I solved it**

```
1. {¬p, ¬q, r} {p} = {¬q,r}
2. {¬q,r} {q} = {r}
3. {¬p, ¬q, s} {¬r1, ¬s, s1} = {¬p,¬q,¬r1,s1}
4. {¬p,¬q,¬r1,s1} {¬p1, ¬q1, r1} = {¬p,¬q,¬p1,¬q1,s1}
5. {¬p,¬q,¬p1,¬q1,s1} {q1} = {¬p,¬q,¬p1,s1}
6. {¬p,¬q,¬p1,s1} {p1} = {¬p,¬q,s1}
7. {¬p,¬q,s1}{¬s1} = {¬p,¬q}
```

I'm doing it right? I'm asking because I see the result is in extended way , the resolution should minimize it,no?

I looked up this lecture:
http://logic.stanford.edu/intrologic/notes/chapter_05.html

Comment: There are some things I don't understand. First of all, I think there is a typo where you describe how the result should be ($\{\neg s\}$ should be $\{\neg s1\}$. Moreover, your solution seems to rely on a "highly condensed" passage, namely line 4: that should be split into three lines. Finally, I don't understand what  your final question means: what do you mean that the result is in extended way, and what should resolution minimize?

Comment: @Leo163 Thank you for the reply, I have attached a lecture slide the describes the way i'm solving the problem to be more clear, Sorry.
My question is how should I solve this kind of resolution problem?
I know by theory C = (C1 − {ℓ}) ∪ (C2 − {l ̅}). that what I apply for every pair of clausal .